# R - factor() function increments my integers by 1

Tags: r

The factor() function is incrementing my zeros to ones and ones to twos. Here's a simple example:

```
# Create some integers
ints <- as.integer(c(1,0,1))
ints
[1] 1 0 1

# Convert these to factors
f_ints <- factor(ints)
f_ints 
[1] 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1

# Great! Let's just check one more thing...
str(f_ints)
Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2

# Woah, whats up with those twos? 

# Screw this, let's go back to integers
ints_again <- as.integer(f_ints)
ints_again
[1] 2 1 2
```

What accounts for this behavior? I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101939/r-from-factor-to-numeric-or-integer-error) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/convert-factor-to-integer) question might explain this, but they're not the same.

Comment: Those questions are basically the same. Factors assign non-zero integers to each of the unique values. They are meant for categorical variables. As the answers in the other questions indicate, do not use `as.integer()` on factors. Use `as.interger(as.character())`. I'm not sure what the specific behavior here is that differs from the other questions.

Comment: "Factors assign non-zero integers to each of the unique values." That's helpful, thanks @MrFlick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert to character before converting to integer like:

```
ints_again <- as.integer(as.character(f_ints))
```